# Complex Mapping form Source having nested classes to destination Having nested Classes

Tags: automapper, mapper

In my application i have to use mapping.

Structure of my Source object is

```
 public class SourceContract  
    {  
     public string ContractNo {get; set;}  
     public string ContractDescription {get; set;}  
    List<SourceSalary> SourceSalaries {get;set;}  
    }
```

Source salary is

```
  public class SourceSalary  
    {  
     public string SalaryNo {get; set;}  
     public int SalaryFixed {get; set;}  

    }
```

Structure of Destination Object is

```
 public class DestinationContract  
    {  
     public string DestinationContractNo {get; set;}  
     public string DestinationDescription {get; set;}  
    List<DestinationSalary> DestinationSalaries {get;set;}  
    }
```

Destination Salary is

```
public class DestinationSalary  
{  
 public string DestinationSalaryNo {get; set;}  
 pubbic int DestinationSalaryFixed {get; set;}  

}
```

Now I am using two mappers

```
 AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<
SourceContract, DestinationContract>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.DestinationContractNo, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ContractNo))  
                .ForMember(dest => DestinationDescription, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ContractDescription))
```

And

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<
        SourceSalary, DestinationSalary>()
                        .ForMember(dest => dest.DestinationSalaryNo, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.SalaryNo))  
                        .ForMember(dest => DestinationSalaryFixed, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.SalaryFixed))
```

**I want to use only one Mapper**

**I am not able to use nested mapping because SourceContract contains List and DestinationContract also contains List**

**Is there any way that I can map in One Mapper?? something like nested mapping**

P.S- I cannot change the names or structure of nethier destination nor  Source.

Comment: Why do you want to use just one mapping? The way you have it now is clear and unambiguous. Should you want to reuse SourceSalary and DestinationSalary in the future within a different class then the mapping is already there for you.

Comment: I want one mapping because everytime i map SourceContract to DestinationContract i have to map SourceSalary to DestinationSalary.

Comment: You only have to create the mapping once when your app starts. Performing the mapping should be a one liner.